# How to assign an incremental id while appending rows in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just need your help.
My problem is I am creating a dynamic form. In my form there is a button and below that is a table.

The scenario is:
1. The user will click the the button
2. After clicking the button the table row will dynamically added. Inside my row there is a textbox

I can do that but how can i do the process after the user click the button. The row will append together with a textbox. But I want to assign a unique ID in a textbox. In my case I want to do this incremental.

Here's my js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[data-item]").on('click',function(){
       $("#grid1 tbody").append("<tr><td><input type='text' value='123' style='width:100px' id='' /></td></tr>");
    });
});
```

Here's my table:

```
<input type="button" name="add" data-item="123" value="ADD" class="test" id="test" />
<table id="grid1" border="1" style="width: 40%">
    <thead>
       <tr>
         <th style="text-align: center;">CODE</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>               
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rochellecanale/xvdMz/

Comment: Note that unless this is html5, your ids should not start with a number :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keep a counter

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var counter = 0;
    $("[data-item]").on('click',function(){
       $("#grid1 tbody").append("<tr><td><input type='text' value='123' style='width:100px' id='in-" + counter++ + "' /></td></tr>");
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tJX2N/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

When you create a new row you can check for the current input's length and add that as a part of id.

```
   $("[data-item]").on('click',function(){
       var $el = $("<tr><td><input type='text' id='myInput" + ($('#grid1').find('input').length +1) + "' value='123' style='width:100px' id='' /></td></tr>");

       $("#grid1 tbody").append($el);
    });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XTjUS/)**

I have another suggestion that instead of keeping the items to be cloned, you can go for templating, least you can put in your html itself like this.

```
<script type="text/html" id="clone">
    <tr><td><input type='text' value='123' style='width:100px' id='' /></td></tr>
</script>
```

and then just use that to clone, this way you keep your html in one place and script in another.

```
  $("[data-item]").on('click',function(){
        var $el =$($.parseHTML($('#clone').html())).find('input').prop('id', "myInput" + ($('#grid1').find('input').length +1) ).end();
       $("#grid1 tbody").append($el);
    });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rDAN4/)**

Comment: Thanks sir it works also. Thanks for the response. :)